# Auto merge of GitHub branches?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

Is there a service I can use to automatically merge the `master` branch on my GitHub repository to the `dev` branch every time I commit to it? I don't want to have a script constantly running on my computer, although if that is the only option I can live with it. I would provide more detail, but I don't even know where to start with this.

Comment: Are you using git with a gui, or with a cli?  Have you tried using either a git alias or bash/powershell scripts to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use git [Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

> After the entire commit process is completed, the `post-commit` hook runs.

So try the following:

```
cd /path/to/project/

echo "#!/bin/sh"                > ./.git/hooks/post-commit
echo "git merge origin/master" >> ./.git/hooks/post-commit

chmod 770 ./.git/hooks/post-commit
```

The would merge `origin/master` into your current working branch after each and every commit. You can obviously tweak it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I am looking for. My only question is, will it work on Windows too, and will it work when people commit using the GitHub website?